Evolving to thermal equilibrium
Suppose I put two identical blocks, one at 200 K and the other at 100 K in thermal contact (both being isolated from the rest of the world). Lets denote this macrostate as (200, 100). We know that eventually both of them will reach the equilibrium macrostate of (150, 150).
The reason the system will eventually reach thermal equilibrium is because the number of microstates coresponding to (150, 150) is overwhelmingly large (i.e. entropy is maximized).
We also know from experience that this equilibrium macrostate will not be reached instantaneously but by going through intermediate macrostates such as (200, 100) -> (190, 110) -> (180, 120) -> etc.
My question is why does the system always evolve through these intermediate states? Starting from the initial macrostate (200, 100), if each microstate is equally probable and the system is randomly sampling microstates, isn't it way more likely for the system to find a microstate of (150, 150) rather than say (199, 101)? So in other words, why is there an "evolution" to the equilibrium state, rather than the system just jumping to the equilibrium state.
[Note - I understand that instantaneously jumping from (200, 100) to (150, 150) is unphysical. I am just trying to understand why it doesn't happen given each microstate is equally probable, and macrostate (150, 150) has WAY more microstates than any of the intermediate macrostates such as (190, 110).]

The most probable microstate is probably a long way from the initial state in configuration space, and the system can only move to the microstates near it in one "step time", where the "step time" is some characteristic time like the period of oscillation of the molecules in the system. If the equilibrium state is $n$ "steps" from the starting state it's going to take about $n^2$ times the step time to get there.

I am thinking now that it is incorrect to say that all microstates are equally probable, since the system is NOT in thermal equilibrium.

Yes, the (average) population of all microstates is equal if and only if the system is in equilibrium.

150 is only if heat capacity isn't a function of temperature... But that is nitpicking

When we shuffle an ordered deck of cards, we know the most likely equilibrium state is a random one with few runs of cards in it. So why, after shuffling the deck once (using a standard riffle shuffle), does it not immediately end up in one of these equilibrium states? Hopefully, the answer is obvious: a riffle shuffle does not permit cards to move arbitrarily far through the deck. The space of possible deck orderings after a single riffle shuffle is very, very small compared to the space of all orderings. So the shuffle can only sample from this much smaller subspace of possible successors.
In the same way, when we put two blocks in contact with each other, we know that only the boundary between them can exchange energy. Therefore, particles on the far side of each block cannot exchange energy with each other. All energy exchange is fundamentally local. This means that after an arbitrarily small time, the set of possible temperatures is quite constrained, and very close to the previously measured temperatures. How close is determined by the thermal conductivity of the blocks. If they are insulators, it can take a very long time to reach the equilibrium state, and each moment of that evolution will only move a small distance through the phase space. If they are conductors, the system can equilibrate quickly and the intermediate states will be more lightly sampled.
In conclusion, we are talking about a physical process, which means that it must necessarily occur over some extended time. Simply sampling a random microstate over the entire universe of microstates is a theoretical convention, but doesn't correspond to reality. Because of locality, the samples must always be selected from "nearby" in the phase space, and the system must "walk" towards the equilibrium states. Equilibrium could be achieved instantly if reality were totally non-local, and every particle could interact with every other particle at any distance. Of course, that would be a very different universe than the one we live in.

Firstly, note that the question is about non-equilibrium statistical physics, a subject that is a lot more complex than equilibrium statistical physics, where the statement about the final equilibrium state comes from.
The claim that the system would necessarily pass through all the intermediate states is not necessarily true, but in mamy cases we can reasonably assume that the two blocks evolve towards equilibrium via exchanging infinitesimally small amounts of energy, which is known as diffusive approximation, leading to the diffusion equation, which in this context is known as heat equation (look up also Fourier law.)
If we believe that this is indeed the case (as is implied implicitly in the Q.), the temperature changes continuously, and hence passes through all the intermediate values. The correspondence between the pairs of temperatures for the two blocks is merely the consequence of the symmetry - as the blocks are assumed identical.

To model this using thermodynamic ideas, first divide the system up into many subsystems. The subsystems are large enough to be macroscopic (say ten billion or more atoms each) but they are small enough that each can be modelled as being in internal equilibrium at each stage of the process, and a little out of equilibrium with its neighbours. This model gives an accurate guide to the process whereby the global system moves to its global equilibrium. You can, of course, also apply statistical reasoning to each subsystem.

As the other comments and answers nicely put it, it is necessary that you go through some of the intermediate states because the equilibrium state is generally quite far from the non-equilibrium initial state of the system. But when you zoom in far enough to where you can “see” the quantum mechanical nature of a system you actually find that not “all” intermediate states are sampled, but merely some subset of states that gets you progressively closer to higher entropy in a more or less direct fashion. This evolution is stochastic, and some of the “jumps” may actually lead you further away from equilibrium! In the case of solid blocks you will mostly be exchanging heat through the excitation and de-excitation of the vibrational modes of the blocks, which can happen in innumerable and highly complicated fashions. This is a manifestation of the fact that on the quantum mechanical level the second law is really only a statistical law, not an absolute. The system will evolve towards equilibrium because it is far more likely to do so, not by any explicit force or desire. Even once reaching macroscopic equilibrium the system will continue to experience fluctuations that take it microscopically “out of equilibrium” (not that you could tell). You were also right to note in your comment that the assumption of equiprobable states only holds water in the microcanonical ensemble at equilibrium. If you are coupled to a surrounding heat bath you would probably prefer to use the canonical ensemble with the associated Boltzmann distribution probabilities.


The reason the system will eventually reach thermal equilibrium is because the number of microstates coresponding to (150, 150) is overwhelmingly large (i.e. entropy is maximized).

No.
The system starts in the known macrostate of (200, 100) and an unknown microstate. That is, there is some set S of microstates for which the macrostate at $t_0$ is (200, 100), and the system is in one of them. The reason we know$^{[1]}$ the system will tend towards the macrostate (150, 150) is because most of the members of S are states for which the macrostate at $t_{\infty}$ is (150, 150). It's not about which macrostate has the most microstates. It's about, of S, which macrostate most of those microstates evolve into.
That is, if you want to know what macrostate the system will be in at time $t_1$, you take all the microstates of S, and for each of them, you evolve them to time $t_1$, then you look at all the resulting macrostates, and you see which macrostate has the most microstates evolving to it.
Over a short time period, there are virtually no microstates in set S that go from (200, 100) to (150, 150). The fact that there are a bunch of microstates in general (that is, without the constraint of starting out at (200, 100)) that end up in the macrostate of (150, 150) at that time is irrelevant, because we know$^{[1]}$ that the system isn't in any of those microstates.
The heuristic that the system will be in the macrostate with most microstates only applies to equilibrium. It doesn't apply to dynamic systems.

Starting from the initial macrostate (200, 100), if each microstate is equally probable and the system is randomly sampling microstates, isn't it way more likely for the system to find a microstate of (150, 150) rather than say (199, 101)?

I wouldn't say that "sampling" is quite the right word. The system doesn't randomly choose a microstate to be in. It is in some definite microstate, we just don't know what it is. But if we were putting it in those terms, the system isn't "sampling" from all the possible microstates, it's "sampling" from all the microstates of set S.
[1] Here, "know" means "the probability of it being false is negligible".
